# Why is cleared appended list in target list when I clear the original list from which I appended?

Tags: python

I need to append content of txt files as sublist into one target list:
final_product would be:

```
[[content file 1],[content of file2],[content of file 3]]
```

I tried to solve it with this code:

```
import os
list_of_files = []
product = []
final_product = []

working_dir = r"U:/Work/"
os.chdir(working_dir)

def create_sublists(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r', encoding = 'ansi') as f:
        for line in f:
            product.append(line.strip()) #append each line from file to product
    final_product.append(product) #append the product list to final_product
    product.clear() #clear the product list
    f.close()

#create list of all files in the working directory
for file in os.listdir(working_dir):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        list_of_files.append(file)

for file in list_of_files:
    create_sublists(file)

print(final_product)
```

I thought that it will work in this way: first file will write its content into list product, this list will be appended into list final_product, the list product will be cleared, then will be appended second file ....
But it creates this:

```
[ [], [], [], [], [], [] ].
```

When I dont use the product.clear() it fills the final_product in this (wrong)way:

```
[[content_file1],[conetn_file1, content_file2],. 
[content_file1,content_file2, content_file3], ....]
```

Then when I use product.clear() it deletes everything appended in final_product. Why?

Comment: There's only one `product` list object which you keep appending over and over. It's all the same list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As deceze points out in the comments, you're always using the same list.

I'm not sure why you are doing this; just create a new list on each iteration.

```
def create_sublists(fname):
    product = []
    with ...
```

Also note, you don't have to close `f` explicitly; it's automatically closed when the with block exits, that's the whole point of with.

Comment: New in python, so it was my stupidity not to do it in this way. You solved my problem. Thank you very much! :)
I will accept you answer after it will be possible (due to time limit)